# serenity bdd default url with spring boot random port number

Tags: spring-boot, serenity-bdd

In tests with Serenity I'm starting my Spring Boot application with a random port.

At some point I need to use a PageObject like this:

```
@DefaultUrl("http://localhost:8080")
public class GreetPage extends PageObject {
}
```

The question is: how can I inject a random port number in the PageObject?

I want to somehow replace the 8080 (which is the default port) with the random port provided by Spring Boot test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the proper URL in the constructor of your Page Object using `setDefaultBaseUrl()`.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked... until I annotated the field that was holding the page object (in a class that implements Task) with '@Steps'.
What is still confusing to me is that when I used the '@DefaultUrl' in the page object I didn't needed the '@Steps' in the Task implementation. But I guess this is due to my limited knowledge of the framework.

Comment: You shouldn't need to annotate a Page Object with @Steps, it's only for step libraries. Serenity will inject any Page Object as long as it extends PageObject.